# Vuex: State management. Which is better way fetch data from state or from server?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, state-management

I'm fetching all my products and putting them into state. I'm not doing any sort of pagination. When a user views a product from a list of products. What should I do?
Should I use some filter with the help of that `productID` and get the selected product other details from the state or use that `productID` and get the data from the server? 
     I also want to know if it changes your answer: What to use if I have 50 products and what should i use if i have 100 products.
Which will be faster and better?

Answer (score 2):

This question seems very opinion based and will probably get closed. There are no definitive answer but here are some leads :

1. 50 and 100 are the same thing, question is more between 50 and 5000. If your list is very large (thousands of items) you should not store it in your state because of performance issue.
2. If all the information you need is already in your state, fetching from the state is faster than calling your API.
3. Keep in mind that fetching from the state will display the products information that might be outdated, while fetching it from your API will give you more recent details (for example, if you display stock of the product)

If your list not too big (max few hundreds of items, depending on their size), you can basically do what you want depending on what you need to do. Each solution has its pros and cons, for example storing everything in state when loading the application might enable you to have an "offline" mode but fetching each item as it is visited will give you more recent infos.

If your list is large, the "classic" way (but not the only one) is to have a list that is paginated and the list only contains main details of your products, not the whole items. When you visit a product, it is then fetched from your API.